# subtract two columns in dataframe if a condition is met

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix-indexing

my dataframe:

```
Dead4   Dead5
0       0
0       0
0       0
1       2
0       0
0       0
1       2
0       0
1       0
0       1
1       1
5      10
```

I want my code to say anytime Dead5 is greater than Dead4 in the same row subtract the two values and place that value in Dead5

```
indices<- (t$Dead5 > t$Dead4) 
t$Dead6[indices]<- (t$Dead6) - (t$Dead5)


Warning message:
In t$Dead6[indices] <- (t$Dead6) - (t$Dead5) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Can some explain what I am doing wrong and help me write a few lines of code that will do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
indices <- (t$Dead5 > t$Dead4) # indices is a logical vector with TRUE and FALSE

t$Dead5[indices] <- (t$Dead5 - t$Dead4)[indices]
```

It also holds for any other operation with your data.frame, like:

```
t$Dead6[indices] <- (t$Dead6 - t$Dead5)[indices]
```

If the column `Dead6` exists. At each side, only the values where `indices` is `TRUE` are taken, so the replacement and replaced values are of the same length, and you don't get the warning.

What you were doing wrong is you were giving as replacement the full `(t$Dead5 - t$Dead4)` vector, which is longer than the number of times the `indices` is `TRUE` (the replaced values in the left).

R was only using the first values of your replacement vector and giving you a warning.

Answer (score 2):

Using `transform()` and `ifelse()`:

```
transform(t, Dead5 = ifelse(Dead5 > Dead4, Dead5-Dead4, Dead5))
```

Comment: this is clever. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(DF)

DT[Dead5 > Dead4, Dead5 := Dead5 - Dead4]
```

You can also do this in `base R` using `within` or `transform`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without `ifelse` and without indexing:

```
indices <- t$Dead5 > t$Dead4 
t$Dead6 <- t$Dead6 - (t$Dead5 * indices)
```